# The integral of the absolute value of the Gaussian curvature of a compact surface

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I want to prove the following theorem:

> Let $S$ be a compact surface, and $N:S\rightarrow \Bbb{S}^2$ the Gauss map, then we have
> $$ \int_{S} |K| \,dA = \int_{\Bbb{S}^2} \#N^{-1} \,dA $$
> where $K$ is the Gaussian curvature of the surface $S$, and $\#N^{-1}$ is the number of the preimages of the Gauss map.

I know that by the stack of record theorem and the fact that $\Bbb{S}^2$ is connected, the value $\#N^{-1}$ should be a constant locally. Also, I know that locally (within a local chart of $S$), we should have

$ \int_{U} |K| \,dA = \int_{N(U)} \,dA $

But I don't know how to prove the theorem globally by involving the number of preimages of the Gauss map. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: No, $\#N^{-1}(q)$ is not a constant function of $q\in\Bbb S^2$. The number of preimages, counted *with orientation sign*, is independent of the regular value $q$, but this is a very different statement. Try examples of a deformed sphere (so that some $q$ have 3 or more preimages) or just a regular torus of revolution. You might want to think directly of the Gaussian curvature as the Jacobian of the Gauss map and then think about the change of variables theorem.

Comment: The number of preimages is not globally constant, otherwise you would get a homeomorphism from say the torus to some number of disjoint copies of the sphere. I think it is constant everyone except some set of measure zero where it has some singularities.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it should be a local constant

Comment: @quarague Not true. You can easily draw examples where the number is $1$ on an open set and $2$ on an open set.